# Vertica interpolate previous value on a concatenated value

Tags: vertica

I have a table A, that has two timestamp columns, A.time1 and A.time2, and another table B that that has one timestamp column B.time. How can I do X interpolate previous value B.time with X being A.time1's hour, minute + A.time2's second?

Something like

```
(
 concat(
   substring(to_char(A.time1), 1, 5)
 , substring(to_char(A.time2), 6)
 )
) interpolate previous value B.time
```

But this will give me an error

Answer (score 1):

First of all - a rather strong suggestion that we should always try to avoid performing string operations on datetime colums.

You could try to typecast your `concat` expression to TIME, by adding `::TIME` to the close-parenthesis before the `interpolate` keyword. But that remains un-elegant.

Try the third expression of the query below (The WITH clause, of course,  is just to demonstrate how it works). Note that I typecast to timestamp, then back to time, as the functions work on timestamps `::`, in Vertica, is a CAST operator:

```
WITH a ( time1            , time2 ) AS (
  SELECT '12:12:12'::time , '00:00:56'::time
)
SELECT
  time1
, time2
, TIMESTAMPADD(
  -- 2. add the seconds contained in time2
    SECOND        -- the unit to add to a timestamp meant by next param
  , SECOND(time2) -- the "second" part of time2 as Integer
  , TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time1::TIMESTAMP,'mi')
    -- 1. cast time1 to timestamp, then truncate to "minute" precision
  )::TIME
  -- 3. cast back to TIME type
FROM a
;
```

Result:

```
time1   |time2   |timestampadd
12:12:12|00:00:56|12:12:56
```